# Google Colab does not run all of one cell

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, google-colaboratory, transfer-learning

I have a training method defined in one cell of a google colab notebook, shown below:

```
def train_model(model, criterion, optimizer, scheduler, num_epochs=25):
    since = time.time()

    best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())
    best_acc = 0.0
    print("Training started")
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
      print("epoch: ", epoch)
      # Training first
      model.train()
      running_loss = 0.0
      running_corrects = 0

      for step, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(train_iter):
        # zero the parameter gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # Track history if only in training
        torch.set_grad_enabled(True)
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        #print(loss)
        # Backwards and optimization:
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        print("step: ",step)
      # statistics

      running_loss += loss.item() * inputs.size(0)
      running_corrects += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

      epoch_loss = running_loss / train_size
      epoch_acc = running_corrects.double() / train_size

      # Use validation set after each epoch
      # Save the best model
      model.eval()
      torch.no_grad()
      num_correct_val = 0
      print("Validation started")
      for step, (inputs, labels) in enumerate(val_iter):
        outputs = model(inputs)
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, 1)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        num_correct_val += torch.sum(preds == labels.data)

      val_acc = num_correct_val.double() / val_size

      if val_acc > best_acc:
        best_acc = val_acc
        best_model_wts = copy.deepcopy(model.state_dict())

    time_elapsed = time.time() - since
    print('Training complete in {:.0f}m {:.0f}s'.format(
        time_elapsed // 60, time_elapsed % 60))
    print('Best val Acc: {:4f}'.format(best_acc))

    # load best model weights
    model.load_state_dict(best_model_wts)
    return model
```

I define my ResNet18 model as below:

```
resnet18 = torchvision.models.resnet18(pretrained=True)
for param in resnet18.parameters():
  param.requires_grad = False
num_ftrs = resnet18.fc.in_features
num_classes = 2
resnet18.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, num_classes)

criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.SGD(resnet18.fc.parameters(), lr = 0.001, momentum = 0.9)

# Decay LR by a factor of 0.1 every 7 epochs
exp_lr_scheduler = lr_scheduler.StepLR(optimizer, step_size=7, gamma=0.1)
```

And I finally call the the train method on my model:

```
try: 
  resnet18 = train_model(resnet18, criterion, optimizer, exp_lr_scheduler)
except:
  pass
```

For some reason, my output is just ( I skipped some steps to make it cleaner and shorter):

```
Training started
epoch:  0
step:  0
step:  1
step:  2
step:  3
step:  4
step:  5
step:  6
.
.
.
step:  155
step:  156
```

Why doesn't google colab execute the rest of the code in the training method? Is it because the number of epochs is large? Or am I doing something wrong in my code?
**Note:** Every block of code is a separate cell in my notebook, and I run them sequentially.

Comment: `except: pass` -> You're throwing away any error output and print no information about it. You're likely running into an error after a few steps and missing the traceback. Temove the try/catch and just run train_model, it will give you more info about why it stops

Comment: It gives me an error about one of the images' Exif data, which is why I had the try catch. Is there any other issue I could be facing?

Comment: Please add the full traceback to the question. Is the exif data error something that stops the execution (i.e., it raises an exception)? If so, you'll need to find the broken file and remove it from your dataset.

Comment: hi i have same problem, google colab process half of code and process finishes in 1 second only, without showing any error or output and dont run rest of codes.